# Assign column with value in the dataset itself using R

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R. 
I got a column of data where there are around 26000 data and the column contains around 1200 unique data. Let's assume the name of the column as 'Breed'.

What I required is,

1. I need to get the frequency for each unique value in the column.

   I have extracted the BreedType and the frequency as shown below. (The breed column is given the name as BreedType )
2. Then if the frequency of each BreedType is less than 50, using an if condition I need to have a new column with 'F' and if greater than 50 need to assign the column with the value of 'Breedtype'.

Here is what I have tried.

```
x<- sort(table(full$Breed),decreasing=T)
w=as.data.frame(x)

names(w)[1] = 'BreedType'

w$TrueFalse<-ifelse(w$Freq<50,F,w$BreedType)
w$TrueFalse
```

But the output given is not what I expected. 
Though the F assign each column correctly, w$BreedType doesn't get the value of BreedType but integers which increase one by one instead of giving the specific BreedType .

Can someone please explain me why the output is not given as expected.

The Breed Column looked like below in the dataset with 20,000 rows and 1200 unique values.

```
 Breed

 Shetland Sheepdog Mix
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Pit Bull Mix
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle
 Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 American Pit Bull Terrier Mix
 Cairn Terrier
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Miniature Schnauzer Mix
 Pit Bull Mix
 Yorkshire Terrier Mix
 Great Pyrenees Mix
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Pit Bull Mix
 Angora Mix
 Flat Coat Retriever Mix
 Queensland Heeler Mix
 Domestic Shorthair Mix
 Plott Hound/Boxer
```

My expected outcome is,

```
BreedType                   Frequency   TrueFalse

Shetland Sheepdog Mix       60          Shetland Sheepdog Mix  
Domestic Shorthair Mix      20          F
Pit Bull Mix                80          Pit Bull Mix
Domestic Shorthair Mix      10          F
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  We don't know what your input data is and using statement `But the output given is not what I expected` will not make much difference.

Comment: Use quotes around "F" if you want the letter "F". `F` is short for false, as you seem to know, since you do use the abbreviation `T` for true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw Data - `full` data frame:

```
> full
#                      Breed
# 1:             Shetland Sheepdog Mix
# 2:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 3:                      Pit Bull Mix
# 4:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 5:       Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle
# 6: Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair
# 7:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 8:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 9:     American Pit Bull Terrier Mix
# 10:                     Cairn Terrier
# 11:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 12:           Miniature Schnauzer Mix
# 13:                      Pit Bull Mix
# 14:             Yorkshire Terrier Mix
# 15:                Great Pyrenees Mix
# 16:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 17:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 18:                      Pit Bull Mix
# 19:                        Angora Mix
# 20:           Flat Coat Retriever Mix
# 21:             Queensland Heeler Mix
# 22:            Domestic Shorthair Mix
# 23:                 Plott Hound/Boxer
# Breed
```

Load data.table library in your workspace

```
library("data.table")
```

Convert `full` dataframe to data table by reference

```
setDT(full)
```

Make a copy of `full` datatable to `dt1`datatable. This is done to have a backup of `full` data table

```
dt1 <- copy(full)
```

Group `dt1` datatable by BreedType (Breed Column), then access the .N internal variable which stores the number of entries in each subset and do the ifelse condition with it. Then save it as Frequency and TrueFalse column variable.

```
dt1[, c("Frequency", "TrueFalse") := .(.N, ifelse(.N < 50, FALSE, Breed)), by = Breed]
```

Display dt1 after the above step

```
> dt1
#                          Breed          Frequency TrueFalse
# 1:             Shetland Sheepdog Mix         1     FALSE
# 2:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 3:                      Pit Bull Mix         3     FALSE
# 4:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 5:       Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle         1     FALSE
# 6: Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair         1     FALSE
# 7:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 8:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 9:     American Pit Bull Terrier Mix         1     FALSE
# 10:                     Cairn Terrier         1     FALSE
# 11:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 12:           Miniature Schnauzer Mix         1     FALSE
# 13:                      Pit Bull Mix         3     FALSE
# 14:             Yorkshire Terrier Mix         1     FALSE
# 15:                Great Pyrenees Mix         1     FALSE
# 16:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 17:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 18:                      Pit Bull Mix         3     FALSE
# 19:                        Angora Mix         1     FALSE
# 20:           Flat Coat Retriever Mix         1     FALSE
# 21:             Queensland Heeler Mix         1     FALSE
# 22:            Domestic Shorthair Mix         8     FALSE
# 23:                 Plott Hound/Boxer         1     FALSE
# Breed Frequency TrueFalse
```

The data you provided do not have frequency of breedtype greater than 50. If you have one, the breedtype will be added instead of FALSE as per the ifelse statement.

Comment: Hi Sathish. Can you explain me what you intended to do here.
dt1 <- full[, .N, by = Breed]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your implementation of frequency per BreedType already works.
This is similar as @Sathish, but using `data.frame` instead of `data.table`

```
testData <- data.frame(BreedType = c("Shetland Sheepdog Mix", "Domestic Shorthair Mix", "Pit Bull Mix", "Domestic Shorthair Mix"),
                   Frequency = c(60, 20, 80, 10), stringsAsFactors = F)
testData$TrueFalse <- testData$BreedType
testData$TrueFalse[testData$Frequency < 50] <- F
```

Output is the same as what you have. However, "FALSE" is converted to a string (instead of being a boolean value) because the column was initialized as a character vector. I'm not sure you can have a mix of booleans and strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count` function from `plyr` package. I've demonstrated an example using the data you provided in question.

```
> library(plyr)

> df <- read.table(text = "Shetland Sheepdog Mix
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Pit Bull Mix
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle
  Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  American Pit Bull Terrier Mix
  Cairn Terrier
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Miniature Schnauzer Mix
  Pit Bull Mix
  Yorkshire Terrier Mix
  Great Pyrenees Mix
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Pit Bull Mix
  Angora Mix
  Flat Coat Retriever Mix
  Queensland Heeler Mix
  Domestic Shorthair Mix
  Plott Hound/Boxer", sep='\n', stringsAsFactors = F, col.names = c('Breed'))
```

Use `plyr::count` function.

```
> df <- count(df, 'Breed')

> df 

##                                 Breed freq
## 1       American Pit Bull Terrier Mix    1
## 2                          Angora Mix    1
## 3                       Cairn Terrier    1
## 4   Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair    1
## 5              Domestic Shorthair Mix    8
## 6             Flat Coat Retriever Mix    1
## ...
## ...


> df$TrueFalse <- ifelse(df$freq >= 3, df$Breed, F)

> df

                                        Breed freq                    TrueFalse
## 1            American Pit Bull Terrier Mix    1                        FALSE
## 2                               Angora Mix    1                        FALSE
## 3                            Cairn Terrier    1                        FALSE
## 4        Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair    1                        FALSE
## 5                   Domestic Shorthair Mix    8       Domestic Shorthair Mix
## 6                  Flat Coat Retriever Mix    1                        FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. This is bit similar to what I tried. Can you let me know what the mistake I have done there? Is the problem with

names(w)[1] = 'BreedType'

Comment: @user3789200 Probably `w$BreedType` is of type `factor`.  Try running `str(w)`.

Comment: @user3789200 Note that I've set `stringsAsFactors = F` in `read.table` call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can also use `base R` `table` to get the frequencies

```
new_df <- data.frame(table(df$Breed))
#                            Var1              Freq
#1        American Pit Bull Terrier Mix    1
#2                           Angora Mix    1
#3                        Cairn Terrier    1
#4    Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair    1
#5               Domestic Shorthair Mix    8
#6              Flat Coat Retriever Mix    1
#7                   Great Pyrenees Mix    1
#8          Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle    1
#9              Miniature Schnauzer Mix    1
#10                        Pit Bull Mix    3
#11                   Plott Hound/Boxer    1
#12               Queensland Heeler Mix    1
#13               Shetland Sheepdog Mix    1
#14               Yorkshire Terrier Mix    1
```

and then  use`ifelse` to get the value of `TrueFalse` column

```
new_df$TrueFalse <- ifelse(new_df$Freq > 2, as.character(new_df$Var1), "F")

#                                 Var1  Freq                TrueFalse
#1        American Pit Bull Terrier Mix    1                        F
#2                           Angora Mix    1                        F
#3                        Cairn Terrier    1                        F
#4    Cairn Terrier/Chihuahua Shorthair    1                        F
#5               Domestic Shorthair Mix    8   Domestic Shorthair Mix
#6              Flat Coat Retriever Mix    1                        F
#7                   Great Pyrenees Mix    1                        F
#8          Lhasa Apso/Miniature Poodle    1                        F
#9              Miniature Schnauzer Mix    1                        F
#10                        Pit Bull Mix    3             Pit Bull Mix
#11                   Plott Hound/Boxer    1                        F
#12               Queensland Heeler Mix    1                        F
#13               Shetland Sheepdog Mix    1                        F
#14               Yorkshire Terrier Mix    1                        F
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need a summarised output, then

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Frequency = .N, TrueFalse = .N > 55), by = Breed]
```